# How do I fix Prisma removing a day from my database on Date type?

Tags: date, datetime, prisma

I am using Prisma in my svelte app to get my data. I have the model below. All of the datetime of type @db.DateTime from the database are returning correctly. All of the shift_date of type @db.Date are subtracting one day from what is stored in my database. The format of the database is type Date and is in this format "YYYY-MM-DD". My database has the value 2023-03-07 and Prisma is returning Mon Mar 06 2023 19:00:00 GMT-0500

```
model TurnReport {
  entry_id   Int      @id(map: "PK_TurnReport") @default(autoincrement())
  comment    String   @db.Text
  datetime   DateTime @db.DateTime
  author     String?  @db.VarChar(100)
  area_id    Int
  shift_date DateTime @db.Date
  shift_num  Int      @db.TinyInt
  ip         String?  @db.VarChar(32)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Evidently, your Db is storing your date as UTC or at least without timezone information, while prisma rehydrates data in your server's local timezone (GMT-0500).

Here are some possible solutions (choose one):

- set your server's timezone to UTC
- use UTC in your application
- convert the column to use timezones ([here's the doc](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/database-connectors/postgresql#native-type-mappings) for reference)
- manage Date in your application code, and offset it before storing it in your database.

Dates are hard. Do not hesitate to sync your db and server timezones.

Comment: I checked the current time zone of my database by using SELECT SYSDATETIMEOFFSET() and it is my current time zone. My app I assume is set to my time zone as I have not specified. I am replacing an MVC app and I also have created a webapi before I knew about Prisma and both of those retrieve the correct date. It is just when I use Prisma the wrong date value is being retrieved. I looked at converting the column to timezones and that looks like it is getting "time with time zone". And just to clarify, this is when I am retrieving the data from my database not sending it to the database.

Comment: I have just noticed that it is taking 4 hours off of each date and datetime. I know it's not accounting for the timezone change but I can't seem to figure out how to fix it when it sends from the server to the client.